# Javascript function doesn't work when display a div that is initially hidden with CSS property display:none

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In my page i keep a div hidden using this css rule:

```
.menu-popup{
    display:none;
    border:1px solid #FFF;
    padding:8px;
    width:100%;
    height:100vh;
    position:fixed;
    top:60px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

So i display this div when i click a button and hide it again when i click outside that div. Everything works fine except the fact that when the div is displayed the filter function inside that div doesn't work. But if i set the display to block for the class:

```
.menu-popup {
    display:block;
}
```

then the filter function works like a charm !!

Can you please help me to figure out what i am doing wrong?
You can take a look at the fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/keepitstupidsimple/dps7vagj/13/

Comment: What is _"the filter function inside that div"_ ? What is expected result ?

Comment: What filter function? Your question only includes CSS, so there aren't any JavaScript functions, and you aren't trying to use the `filter` property. (Hint: You need to provide a complete question here and not depend on third party links to make it understandable)

Comment: It filters the categories inside this div !! You can see it on the fiddle i posted above.

Comment: Your fiddle contains insane amount of unintelligible JavaScript to do god knows what. It's probably interfering somehow. Consider taking the advice in the fiddle's URL and keep it stupid simple.

Comment: I have checked your fiddle. Binding the click event on the whole document isn't wise if you want to add multiple functions to some buttons. Keep them separated by binding the click event on the button itself instead of the document.

Comment: @Niet the Dark Absol i am using this plugin: https://mixitup.kunkalabs.com/ so i can filter some options inside my div.

Comment: @KarelG can you give me an example on my jsfiddle how can i do that as i am new on Javascript. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Use rawgit to include the plugin on the fiddle as an external resource.  And use the javascript cog to include you jquery, not the external resources.

Comment: Is requirement to display `div` element within `.container` element filtered by  `.filter` button `data-category` corresponding to `class` of `.container > div`   ?

Comment: @Quentin i apologise if my question is not understandable but i am trying to be as more specific as i can. My english level isnt so good and i am new in programming and also new here in the community. I promise will do my best.  Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using delegates?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is with the the plugin initialization code,

```
$('#container').mixItUp();
```

Looks like this works only if the content is visible. So change this call after the show function works on `$('.menu-popup')`.

Check this new [**fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/dps7vagj/30/).

Comment: You are awesome! This works perfect !!!

Comment: Uh, that will be re-initializing every time it's made visible, no?

Comment: @Taplar Re-initializing is not needed. I'll make that change.